# Java Android : How to convert an abstract class to a singleton with dagger

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, abstract-class, dagger-2

I have this helper class that constructs a pojo. I'm using firebase to fetch objects and create one object.

PROBLEM : This class is being called a lot, and I think it would be more economic to not keep creating its instance.

I tried doing it myself, but failed embarrassingly, still learning.

**THE CLASS**

```
public abstract class FetchPost implements ValueEventListener {
    public abstract void event(Post post);

    private Post   post;
    private String postId;

    public FetchPost(String postId) {
        AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
            this.postId = postId;
            Nodes.appRef("/posts/" + postId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(this);
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        getUser();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError e) {

    }

    private void getUser() {
        Nodes.Users.profile(post.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot d) {
                User user = d.getValue(User.class);
                post.setUser(user);
                getSound();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError e) {
            }
        });
    }

    public void getSound() {
        Nodes.appRef("sounds/" + post.getObjectId()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Sound sound = dataSnapshot.getValue(Sound.class);
                sound.setSoundId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                post.setSound(sound);
                event(post);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError e) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How can I construct this class such that I can use with Dagger as a singleton?

I tried using a normal class with an interface in place of the abstract method, but everytime i call `FetchPost()` with an interface as an event listener, all the previous call are replaced.

Comment: You can't make a singleton out of an abstract class, because you can't instantiate an abstract class.  You can make an instance of a subclass and make a singleton out of that, but that's the most you can do.

Comment: @GabeSechan, so for my issue, you think it's just better to keep doing `new FetchPost(){}` ?

Comment: Impossible to say as I don't know what you're actually trying to do here-  how often does the data refresh, how is this class used, etc.  While you can't make a singleton of the class, there are other solutions to avoid repeated requests (such as storing the results in statics and only launching the request when needed.  Or not making this class abstract, I have no idea why it is).

Comment: @GabeSechan, oryt, I guess I'll just try to lower the number of times this gets called. Thanks.